# Is '/' really a valid device to find with pcap?

Tags: windows, network-programming, libpcap, winpcap

I'm messing around with libpcap, and running this test code:

```
char* device, errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

printf("Looking for device...\n");
device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuff);

if (device == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuff);
    return 1;
}

printf("Device found: %s\n", device);
```

It works, but it outputs the following:

```
Looking for device...
Device found: \
```

I'm on Windows (10), and the code that follows this continues to work (I can post if necessary), so it *seems* that this is a valid device, but the naming seems strange to me. I'm coming from linux, so I'm used to seeing `ethX`, etc.

If this isn't normal, what should I be seeing?

Comment: Unless pcap uses a particularly odd nomenclature, that isn't a valid device name.    My best guess is that pcap_lookupdev is returning a UTF-16 string (that being the native encoding for Windows) so when you print it as a narrow string you only see the first character.  Try `%ws` in the call to printf() and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: `%ws` did make a difference. It output: `\Device\NPF_{BF9D6116-...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This appears to be a bug, design limitation, or perhaps just poor documentation in winpcap.](https://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2007-May/001863.html)

The `pcap_lookupdev` function is declared to return `char *` but actually returns `wchar_t *`.  It isn't clear to me whether this is also true of related functions, e.g., whether `pcap_open_live` actually expects a UTF-16 string for the device name.  If your code works (without having explicitly converted the string to ASCII) then presumably all device names arguments are *actually* UTF-16.

That's pretty lousy practice, but it may have been considered a necessary evil in order to ensure cross-platform compatibility.